# ComboBox must define ComboBox.ItemTemplate when binding ItemsSource with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I'm using [Reactive UI](https://reactiveui.net/) for my project.
I use it for binding an **ObservableCollection** to **ComboBox.ItemsSource**.
Below is what I am doing:

**HomeViewModel.cs**

```
public class HomeViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    public string UrlPathSegment => "HOME";

    public IScreen HostScreen => null;

    private SourceList<int> _myList { get; } = new SourceList<int>();

    private readonly IObservableCollection<int> _targetCollection = new ObservableCollectionExtended<int>();

    public IObservableCollection<int> TargetCollection => _targetCollection;

    #endregion

    public HomeViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                _myList.Add(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });

        _myList.Connect()
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Bind(_targetCollection)
            .Subscribe();
    }
}
```

**HomeView.xaml**

```
<VirtualizingStackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="CountriesComboBox">

    </ComboBox>
</VirtualizingStackPanel>
```

When I open the application and click on **ComboBox**, an exception was thrown:
[image]

I define **ItemTemplate** in **ComboBox.ItemTemplate**, the ComboBox works successfully.

```
<ComboBox Name="CountriesComboBox">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

My question is:

- Can I use the collection binding without defining default template for ComboBox ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding to the `ItemsSource` property like this in the code-behind of the view like this:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.TargetCollection, v => v.CountriesComboBox.ItemsSource);
```

...you could bind it in your XAML markup using the built-in markup extension:

```
<ComboBox Name="CountriesComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding TargetCollection, Mode=OneTime}">
```

Then you can get rid of the `ItemTemplate` at the expense of some compile time safety.

The other option is to set the `DisplayMemberPath` instead of the `ItemTemplate` property and keep the call to `OneWayBind`:

```
<ComboBox Name="CountriesComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="." />
```

Comment: @Redplane: Does this answer your question?